# How to check If "mywindow" tab of the browser is active or not in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, onblur

Actually i am making website of online test/exam in asp.net using c# 4.0. And for giving exam the user needs to click on a button which will open a window with a JavaScript function.

```
    function OpenForm() {
 window.open('Test.aspx', 'mywindow',
'fullscreen=yes,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no');
```

}

And the thing i want is, while a Exam is going on, if user changes its tab or open a folder in his/her pc then i want to close the window i.e. "mywindow". i know its not possible in asp.net to achieve this so want to know how can i achieve this in javascript or jquery?

i have search out the net for few answers and now i know how to call a JavaScript function every time my "test.aspx" or "mywindow" page loads.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
 <script type="text/javascript">   

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{ 
    yourFunction(); 
} 

function yourFunction() 
{ 

    alert("aaa"); 
} 


function pageLoad() 
{ 
    if(!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) 
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

} 
</script> 


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate> 
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="6000">

            </asp:Timer> 
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</form>
```

//i need to right the logic in yourFunction() to check whether "mywindow" or "test.aspx" is active or not if yes then i will display a message on alert("u are disqualified") and then close the "test.aspx"

Please someone help me out with this!!! please...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it...  I tested in Chrome/Opera/Firefox/IE... In IE it asked for permission to close the window on all the others it closed automatically....Not sure how to get around the IE bug at the moment.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).focus();
    $(window).blur(function () {
        window.opener.BadStudent();
        window.close();
    });
    $('#close').click(function () {
        window.close();
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT:  This script is placed on the page that they would end up on.  Also I added a form element just to ensure that the window wouldn't close when a child element was selected and I didn't have any issues.

EDIT 2:  The IE bug was due to javascript not opening the window. so insted use...
`<a href="#" id="OpenWindow">Link</a>`

and then...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function BadStudent () {
            alert("Your a bad student");
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#OpenWindow').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                Popup = window.open("@Url.Action("test")").focus();
            });
        });
</script>
```

The script that goes on the child window is still valid.  Also this was done using jQuery for the selectors.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr Jared. I will try this on my project and let you know if i have any problem. Anywayz thaks a lot. :)

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee No problem. Since this is your first post on here whenever you ask a question and get help.  If the answer solves your problem be sure to accept the answer and upvote it(this helps your rating as well as the person that answered).